# show/hide div based on text input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make something where the user types in a "password" and it shows a div depending on which password is typed in. I saw something like this work with numbers but I am confused on how to make it work with letters.  How can I make this work? Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3XGGn/405/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttontest").click(function(){
            
        if ($('#full_day').val() == yes) {   
            $("#yes").show("fast"); 
        }
        if ($('#full_day').val() == no) {   
            $("#no").show("fast"); 
        } 
        
        else {
            $("#yes").hide("fast");    
            $("#no").hide("fast");
            $("#incorrect").show("500");
        }
    });
    $("#full_day").change(function() {
        $("#incorrect").hide("500");
    });
                

});
```

```css
#yes {display:none;}
#no {display:none;}
#incorrect {display:none;}
```

```html
<p>type "yes" or "no"</p>
<div id="yes">
That's Correct!
</div>
<div id="no">
Also correct!
</div>
<div id="incorrect">
Sorry, Try again!
</div>
<input type='text' id="full_day"/>
<input type='button' id="buttontest" value="clickme"/>
```

Comment: `yes` and `no` need to be wrapped in quotes (`'yes'`, `'no'`) - they are strings

Comment: rewrote it for you, you shouldn't be creating a new jquery object each time you reference an element. use variables instead. And use `$.on()` instead of `$.click()` and `$.change()` http://jsfiddle.net/3XGGn/406/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will accept "yes" and "no" strings in any case (Lower/Upper) even in mixed case as well.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#buttontest").click(function () {
                $(".all").hide("fast");
                if ($('#full_day').val().toLocaleLowerCase() == "yes") {
                    $("#yes").show("fast");
                } else if ($('#full_day').val().toLocaleLowerCase() == "no") {
                    $("#no").show("fast");
                } else {
                    $("#incorrect").show("500");
                }
            });
            $("#full_day").change(function () {
                $("#incorrect").hide("500");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #yes {
            display: none;
        }

        #no {
            display: none;
        }

        #incorrect {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>type "yes" or "no"</p>
    <div class="all" id="yes">
        That's Correct!
    </div>
    <div class="all" id="no">
        Also correct!
    </div>
    <div class="all" id="incorrect">
        Sorry, Try again!
    </div>
    <input type='text' id="full_day" />
    <input type='button' id="buttontest" value="clickme" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot about it being case sensitive, .toLocaleLowerCase works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You need to change `yes` to `'yes'` and `no` to `'no'`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#buttontest").click(function(){
if ($('#full_day').val() == 'yes') {   
 $("#yes").show("fast"); 
}
else if ($('#full_day').val() == 'no') {   
 $("#no").show("fast"); 
} 
else {
 $("#yes").hide("fast");    
 $("#no").hide("fast");
 $("#incorrect").show("500");
}
});

$("#full_day").change(function() {
$("#incorrect").hide("500");
});

});
```

```css
#yes {display:none;}
#no {display:none;}
#incorrect {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>type "yes" or "no"</p>
<div id="yes">
That's Correct!
</div>
<div id="no">
Also correct!
</div>
<div id="incorrect">
Sorry, Try again!
</div>
<input type='text' id="full_day"/>
<input type='button' id="buttontest" value="clickme"/>
```